# Unable to move on to next page http://indianvisa-bangladesh.nic.in/visa/Get_Appointment via httpClient 4.4

Tags: java, http-headers, httpclient, httpresponse, setcookie

Hiii
Update 2:
thanks 4 the help.
I got the cookies now but i am stuck on the same page.
I added cookie as header with request but i got the same page as response.
Don't know i m doing wrong.
Please guide me.

```
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient httpclient = new org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient(); 
    try {
        // Create a local instance of cookie store
        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

        // Create local HTTP context
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        // Bind custom cookie store to the local context
        System.out.println("Binding Cookie from Cookie Store="+this.cookies);
        String c=this.cookies.replaceAll("Set-Cookie: ", "");
        String c1=c.replaceAll(";path=/", "");
        System.out.println("c="+c1);
        String []ar=c1.split("=");
        System.out.println("a[0]="+ar[0]);
        System.out.println("a[1]="+ar[1]);
        BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie(ar[0], ar[1]);
        cookie.setDomain("indianvisa-bangladesh.nic.in");
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookieStore.addCookie(cookie); 
        httpclient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);


        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://indianvisa-bangladesh.nic.in/visa/Get_Appointment");

        System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());

        // Pass local context as a parameter
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        if (entity != null) {
            System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
        }
        List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Local cookie: " + cookies.get(i));
        }
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println("Page contect="+result);

        // Consume response content
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

    } finally {
        // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
        // shut down the connection manager to ensure
        // immediate deallocation of all system resources
        //httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try iterate `httpclient.getCookieStore();`

Here examples http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.http.client.CookieStore

http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-4-cookies

Comment: thanks for d help. I got the cookies but i am unable to move on to next page don't know why. i provided cookie as a header with the request but i am still stuck at same page.

Comment: You are doing a request to a page and you get the content, i don't understand why did you expect another page or how you want your code to move to another one, can you explain what you try to do to try to help you because your code is not trying to move to another page

Comment: i mean i m not getting the content even though i am providing cookie with the contxt and it is being is being redirected where as when i try this in browser, it works perfectly.

Comment: maybe because the browser supports and execute JS and able to follow redirection... i think you need to work with selenium  webdriver  http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp